# color changes for ipad

Tags: css, ipad

ok I build this website: http://www.thedoggyduderanch.com/

but the phone number at reservation area changes color to purple in iPad, I don't know why. I tested the site with online tools, as I don't have any ipad. & the text looks good with white color. but my client saying that it changes color to purple in iPad. how can I solve it?

the css for the phone number is:

```
.reserve-phn {
    margin-left: 1em;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all my suggesting is instead of span use the link

`<a class="reserve-phn" href="tel:435-772-3105">435-772-3105</a>`

then concerning the css just do

`.reserve-phn, .reserve-phn:visited {
    margin-left: 1em;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this meta tag to your page to keep iOS Safari from reformatting your phone numbers:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Comment: thanks for your help. really appreciated it. I added the meta tag, lets see what my client says. @Chishiki

Comment: its ok, not a problem. we don't want it to be a link at this moment. @Setrino